# How to clear or delete the Cookies from Web Browser control in windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i want to clear cookies of a web browser control every time when the page loaded,how can i do this .

Thanks you

Comment: this facility is added in WP8 not in WP7

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string source = webBrowser.Source.ToString();
var cookies = webBrowser.GetCookies();

foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
{
        cookie.Discard = true;
        cookie.Expired = true;
}
```

If you want to clear cookies for a certain domain you can also add a check to foreach loop :

```
if (cookie.Domain.Contains("someDomain"))
```